# Compile a Module

Tags: compile

Itried first to compile this `Module`

```
cdl4u2 := Module[{lst1, lst2, lst3},
  lst1 = RandomSample[Range[0, 9], 4];
  lst2 = RandomSample[Complement[Range[0, 9], lst1], 4];
  lst3 = RandomSample[Complement[Range[0, 9], lst1, lst2], 2];
  {lst1, lst2, lst3}]
```

first tried `Compile[expresion]` but the syntax ask at least 2 items, so I tried with

```
pdya = Compile[{a}, Module[{lst1, lst2, lst3},
   lst1 = RandomSample[Range[0, 9], 4];
   lst2 = RandomSample[Complement[Range[0, 9], lst1], 4];
   lst3 = RandomSample[Complement[Range[0, 9], lst1, lst2], 2];
   {lst1, lst2, lst3}]]
```

where a isw a dummy parameter..   well finally it looks like I created a

```
CompiledFunction[{10, 11.2, 5468}, {
Blank[Real]}, {{3, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 3}}, {{0, {2, 0, 0}}, {
  9, {2, 0, 1}}, {4, {2, 0, 8}}, {2, {2, 0, 9}}, {-1, {2, 0, 5}}, {
  1, {2, 0, 3}}}, {0, 10, 1, 0, 4}, {{6, 1, 2}, {6, 0, 4}, {41, 258, 
  2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6}, {35, 6, 2, 0}, {6, 5, 7}, {3, 2}, {36, 
  4, 7, 2, 0}, {4, 7, 2, -1}, {
  42, "RandomSample", 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 8, 2, 1, 1}, {6, 1, 6}, {6, 0, 
  2}, {41, 258, 2, 0, 6, 2, 0, 5, 2, 0, 7}, {35, 7, 2, 0}, {6, 5, 
  4}, {3, 2}, {36, 2, 4, 2, 0}, {4, 4, 6, -1}, {
  42, "Complement", 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {
  42, "RandomSample", 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 8, 2, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 2}, {6, 0, 
  7}, {41, 258, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6}, {35, 6, 2, 2}, {6, 5, 
  4}, {3, 2}, {36, 7, 4, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 2, -1}, {
  42, "Complement", 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3}, {
  42, "RandomSample", 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 9, 2, 1, 2}, {34, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 
  0, 3}, {1}}, 
Function[{a}, 
Module[{lst1, lst2, lst3}, lst1 = RandomSample[
Range[0, 9], 4]; lst2 = RandomSample[
Complement[
Range[0, 9], lst1], 4]; lst3 = RandomSample[
Complement[
Range[0, 9], lst1, lst2], 2]; {lst1, lst2, lst3}]], Evaluate]
```

nothing like I expected  this is a deg.exe file that I can use without a mathematica working in    Maybe I want something that only can be done using a cpp compiler ???  thanks for any help ans sorry if I made mistakes in english ...

Comment: Indeed, `Compile` produces dynamic libraries that can be called only by Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks Henrik Schumacher, I supose need to make it in C or C++ or Java ...  I had already the idea that it'd be closed to Mathematica  ... at least had worked out the algorithm    it'll be easier to write C

Comment: You can always apply `ExportString` to the compiled function and browse the actual C-code. You might recycle some of the code snippets in an external C- or C++-program.

Comment: Tried it Henrik Schumacher... well it's not like can use ... I appreciate your advice, maybe next opportunity     this would have to be cooked old way  in Tontöpfen!

Comment: _rofl_ What??? Oo ("Tontöpfchen" is such an odd German word... where did you get it from?)

Comment: Got it in Google translator,   in spanish we say "cazuelas de barro" and still I have some at home   but can not use with modern induction kitchenfires ... but older make veri interesting sauces working slowly over woodcoal!   believe me I'm spanish   we are concerned in how to prepare specialities